# Stop Visual Studio 2022 from Auto Opening Code Tab

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2022

I'm running an asp.net solution in debug mode in Visual Studio 2022. While running, VS keeps automatically opening a code tab and setting focus to a line in it where there are no breakpoints. I close the tab to see the code I'm debugging, but as soon as the code resumes, VS opens the tab again.
There are no breakpoints in the tab it keeps opening. Usually it's a master page, but sometimes it's an aspx page.
I use ReSharper, so that may be the culprit. I can't find a setting in R# or VS that controls this behavior.
How do I turn this off?

I looked through settings, but found none to control this.
I commented out the line it keeps bringing into view, but it only stops at another line near it.
The line isn't throwing an exception, and it's valid code.
The highlighted line runs successfully.
I can't figure out why it's even highlighting that code or why it opens the tab.

Answer (score 0):

Hum, ok, assuming this is web forms.

do a clean project. And ONLY if this is a web site "application", then delete the bin folder. Go up one level (to project level, and delete the .vs folder. Now try a re-build all, see if that helps.

And of course check this setting:

[image]

Comment: I followed every step to no avail. I toggled the setting on and off, restarting VS between setting changes. This infuriating behavior continues. I'll log a bug and hope it gets fixed. Thanks for your help!